# Querying after populate with RegExp in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get docs depending on a regex applied to model populated from mapReduce, but I can't accomplish it:

```
Article.authors(function(err, model){
  model.find({ '_id.surname': /^A/ })
       .populate({ path: '_id', model: 'Author' })
       .exec(function(err, authors){
         ...
       });
});
```

Can you help me? The above don't shows me anything...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
model.find( { '_id.surname': new RegExp('^A') } )
     .populate({ path: '_id', model: 'Author' })
     .exec(function(err, authors){
       ...
     });
```

The main part here is that `/^A/` is a MongoDB shell specific syntax, where in JavaScript you will have to use `new RegExp('^A')`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want the key _id.surname. Might you not be actually looking for just the surname field ? so it should be

```
Article.authors(function(err, model){
  model.find({ 'surname': /^A/ })
     .populate({ path: '_id', model: 'Author' })
     .exec(function(err, authors){
       ...
     });
});
```